# Get Region from AWS CLI using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have installed [AWS-CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-windows.html) in my local machine. I have created a configuration profile. But I don't how to get the region from the profile from my code .

**Code**

```
var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({ profile: node_env });
console.log(credentials);
```

I can get `access ID` but I couldn't get the region. Is there is any other way to get the region ?

Answer (score 1):

When you set credentials using `aws configure`, it creates two files

- `~/.aws/config`
- `~/.aws/credentials`

region and output information save under `~/.aws/config` and `access_key` and `secret_key` store under `~/.aws/credentials`.

To get using `aws-cli`

`aws configure get region --profile test`

It will return the region for profile test.

But in case of Nodejs it a little bit different, it [does not set region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html) and you get null region when you print the credentials.

> The SDK for JavaScript doesn't select a Region by default. However,
>   you can set the Region using an environment variable, a shared config
>   file, or the global configuration object.

So you have two option.

**Using a Shared Config File**

> Much like the shared credentials file lets you store credentials for
>   use by the SDK, you can keep your Region and other configuration
>   settings in a shared file named config that is used by SDKs. If the
>   AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG environment variable has been set to a truthy
>   value, the SDK for JavaScript automatically searches for a config file
>   when it loads. Where you save the config file depends on your
>   operating system:

`Linux, macOS, or Unix users: ~/.aws/config`

`Windows users: C:\Users\USER_NAME\.aws\config`

If you don't already have a shared config file, you can create one in the designated directory. In the following example, the config file sets both the Region and the output format.

```
[default]
   region=us-west-2
   output=json
```

[setting-region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html) vs [loading-node-credentials-shared](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-shared.html)

**Order of Precedence for Setting the Region**

- The order of precedence for Region setting is as follows:
- **If a Region is passed to a client class constructor, that Region is used. If not, then...**
- **If a Region is set on the global configuration object, that Region is used. If not, then...**
- If the `AWS_REGION` environment variable is a truthy value, that **Region** is used. If not, then...
- If the `AMAZON_REGION` environment variable is a truthy value, that **Region** is used. If not, then...
- If the `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` environment variable is set to a truthy value and the shared credentials file `(~/.aws/credentials or the path indicated by AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE)` contains a Region for the configured profile, that **Region** is used. If not, then...
- If the `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` environment variable is set to a truthy value and the config file `(~/.aws/config or the path indicated by AWS_CONFIG_FILE)` contains a **Region** for the configured profile, that **Region** is used.

Or you can read `~/.aws/config` as a file, not as AWS config in nodejs with `SharedIniFileCredentials` approach.

Comment: thank you, best detailed answer on this that I've seen.  It is now referenced in all my source code so that someone can understand why I have passed all these environment variables in via docker-compose